# Team Foundation server 2013 backlog order API

Tags: tfs, backlog

I need to know if any API are available to automate the backlog order. Since its cumbersome to drag and drop when PBI is very large.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you have? TFS 2013.4 has a feature that removes 99% of this need.

Comment: Version 12.0.30723.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest api's for this are currently not available however you can update the "Backlog Priority" field from your application of choice. I have, in the past, used excel to bulk move items around when the backlog I large. If you have Team Explorer installed you can use the Team tab on Excel to connect to your backlog query and reorder to your hearts content.

In 2013.4 Microsoft have updated the backlog to allow a right-click "move to top" and "move to position x" to remove the need for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This drag n drop in TFS must be using some API. To achieve my automation I need to call this API. Currently I am able to get order of work item. I have to pass this order to the respective API function. As per ur comment, there are not API's you mentioned. Are you sure of this??? I went through TFS SDK myself, I am also unable to find the respective API. Just double chedking how you concluded this.kidnly let me know